# UnboundLocalError at /subscribe/ local variable 'customer' referenced before assignment

Tags: python-3.x, pythonanywhere

Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
/home/Khader/dating_app/checkout/views.py, line 78, in subscribe
customer = stripe.Customer.create( …
Local vars
Variable    Value
order
<Order: 62-2023-10-25 07:30:17.856209+00:00-Peer Khader Mydeen>
order_form

payment_form

plan_ids
{'plan_F5ey2nnZwy5v8Q': '3 Monthly',
'plan_F5eyGdYCvZPtON': 'Monthly',
'plan_F5eyNlWXHig7YB': '6 Monthly'}
request
<WSGIRequest: POST '/subscribe/'>
subscription
None
/home/Khader/.virtualenvs/dating_app-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/stripe/api_resources/customer.py, line 604, in create
cls._static_request( …
Local vars
/home/Khader/.virtualenvs/dating_app-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/stripe/api_resources/abstract/api_resource.py, line 152, in _s[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuqFP.jpg)tatic_request

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to use a variable called "customer" before you have defined it. Look at the code and make sure that you are defining "customer" before you try to use it.